# Fable F# to Javascript: Parameterless functions being given a parameter when referenced

Tags: f#, fable-f#

I am having difficulty referring to parameterless functions in Fable.

With this example:

```
let f1 () = 
    1

let someRefTof1 = f1
```

I'd expect the generated js to look something like this:

```
function f1() {
    return 1;
}

var someRefTof1 = f1;
```

but what I actually get is:

```
function f1() {
    return 1;
}

var someRefTof1 = exports.someRefTof1 = function someRefTof1(arg00_) {
    return f1(arg00_);
};
```

I'm unclear on the purpose of `arg00_` or how to avoid it being generated?

(As a bit of background, I am struggling to call a function in an external js library which expects a function to be passed as a parameter)

---

Edit:

**Background**

The above is what i believe to be a minimal, verifiable, reproduction of my question but, after comments, I thought it may be useful to provide a touch more context on why this is causing issues. What I am actually trying to do is use angularjs from Fable.

So my example looks more like this:

```
let app = AngularFable.NgFable.angular.``module``("app",[||])

type TestCtrl() = 
    member this.Val1() = "boom";

app?controller("test", TestCtrl)
```

which gets compiled to:

```
var app = exports.app = angular.module("app", []);

var TestCtrl = exports.TestCtrl = function () {
    function TestCtrl() {
        _classCallCheck(this, TestCtrl);
    }

    TestCtrl.prototype.Val1 = function Val1() {
        return "boom";
    };

    return TestCtrl;
}();

_fableCore.Util.setInterfaces(TestCtrl.prototype, [], "App.TestCtrl");

app.controller("test", function (unitVar) {
    return new TestCtrl();
});
```

with `unitVar` being the problematic parameter introduced in this example. When I use this in my html with something like:

```
  <div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="test as vm">
      {{vm.Val1()}}
    </div>
  </div>
```

I run into an [unknown provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=unitVarProvider%20%3C-%20unitVar%20%3C-%20test) error whereas if I simply change the compiled javascript to remove the `unitVar` parameter from the last line like this:

```
app.controller("test", function () {
    return new TestCtrl();
});
```

then my example works as expected.

I'd really like to know if there is a way to avoid having the Fable compiler generate this parameter. I'm 99% sure this reduces to the same problem as in my original question but I've included this additional context to better explain why this is an issue

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but the function isn't really parameterless, it has a single parameter of type unit.

Comment: Yeah, good point but it maps the original 'paramterless' function as expected - it's just when a reference is made to that function that the problem arises

Comment: What problem exactly? The only issue I can see with `arg00_` is if you pass it to some javascript code that uses `f.length` to get the declared number of arguments, which is highly discouraged practice. Otherwise it shouldn't change anything.

Comment: @Tarmil When I call `.controller()` from the angularjs library with the generated function it fails with an [unknown provider error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=unitVarProvider%20%3C-%20unitVar%20%3C-%20test) whereas if I intercept the generated javascript code and remove the superfluous argument (with no other changes whatsoever) it works as expected.

Comment: @Tarmil I'm not sure I managed to explain that properly in my previous comment so I've now edited the question to provide a much fuller explanation of why this is an issue :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thank you very much for your question and detailed explanations. There're two things here that are a bit tricky and are caused by optimisations both of the F# compiler and Fable.

- In the AST provided by the F# compiler, methods (functions that are members of a type or module) are compiled as *usual* methods as in C#. This is for optimization.
- However, when you create an anonymous lambda or make a reference to a method, the F# compiler will keep F# semantics, that is, all functions have a single argument (as John Palmer says, `unit` is an argument too) and can be curried.

Ok, this info is just to make clear why the F# compiler/Fable represent methods and lambdas differently. Let's go with the issue of argumentless functions: the obvious solution would be of course to remove the F# compiler generated argument for functions accepting `unit` (as it's already done for methods). In fact, I also had problems with libraries like Mocha because of this.

I did try to remove the `unit` argument at the beginning but I got fails in some scenarios because of this. TBH, I don't remember now exactly which tests were failing but because of the expectation that there'll be always an argument, in some cases function composition or inlining was failing when the `unit` argument was removed.

Other attempts to modify the semantics of F# functions in the JS runtime have always failed because they don't cover all scenarios. However, we can be more lenient with delegates (`System.Func<>`) as it's usually safe to assume these ones should behave more like functions in languages like C# or F#. I can try to remove the unit argument just for delegates and see what happens :)

For more info about sending F# functions to JS code you can check the [documentation](http://fable.io/docs/interacting.html#Calling-F-code-from-JavaScript).

**UPDATE**: Scratch all that, please try fable-compiler@0.6.12 and fable-core@0.6.8. This version eliminates `unit` arguments, the solution was actually simpler than I thought and (hopefully) shouldn't create issues with existing projects. (The explanation about methods and lambdas compiled differently still applies.)